# How to get the value from <input> tag using java in Selenium web driver when the Value attribute is generated dynamically

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

The HTML I am trying to operate on:

```html
<select id="GlobalDateTimeDropDown" class="combo"
    onchange="CalculateGlobalDateTime('Time',this.value)" name="GlobalDateTimeDropDown">
       <option value="+5.5" selected="selected"> … </option>
       <option value="+12"> … </option>
       <option value="+8"> … </option>
       <option value="+2"> … </option>
    </select>
    <input id="GlobalDateTimeText" class="combo" type="text" name="GlobalDateTimeText"       value="" style="width:215px;padding:2px;" readonly="readonly"></input>
```

Java Code:

```java
WebElement values=driver.findElement(By.id("GlobalDateTimeText")).getAttribute("Value");
System.out.println(values);
```

Output:
Blank

Comment: So you're trying to get the `value` attribute of the `input element` and not the values of the `option` elements contained within the `select` element, correct?

Answer (score 7):

To select the input value you'll need to use an xpath selector as using `by.id` will find the select element as they share the same `id` - which is bad practice as they really should be unique. Anyway, try:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='GlobalDateTimeText']")).getAttribute(‌​"value");
```

Answer (score 0):

Code should be something like this

```java
WebElement dropDown = driver.findElement(By.id("GlobalDateTimeText"));
Select sel = new Select(dropDown);
List<WebElement> values = sel.getOptions();
for(int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++)
{
   System.out.println(values.get(i).getText());
}
```

Comment: The important thing to note here is that it does not matter if the value is generate dynamically. The HTML is static, after it is modified by the Javascript.

Comment: Did not understand the comment. Do you mean to say you are not able to get the text from the drop down using the code?

Comment: @Vinay: Am able to get the value from the drop down. Once the value is selected, a <input value=""> will be updated with a string. I am unable to get that value

Comment: @udi08s Can you try following code. When you specify something for getAttribute(""), property is case sensitive. You have specified Value instead value                                                        WebElement values=driver.findElement(By.id("GlobalDateTimeText")).getAttribute("value");
System.out.println(values);

Comment: @udi08s To select the `input` value you'll need to use an xpath selector as using `by.id` will find the `select` element as they share the same `id` - which is bad practice as they really should be unique. Anyway, try:  `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='GlobalDateTimeText']")).getAttribute("value");`

Comment: @MarkRowlands: YOu should post that as a separate answer, so you can get credit for it.

Comment: I'll make the question more clear. I do have the same problem. I can see a text in the web page. When I inspect element on it using firebug, I cannot see the text. I can see only the element and it's attributes. But I can see the text on the DOM section in which there is variable called "value" with the text. Is it possible to get that value?